# Mocking global HTTP requests for all suites in Angular and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In my `app.config` I am using a service called [ui-router-extras FutureStates](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future) to dynamically create states from the results of a REST call. One of the side effects of this is that when my tests run, since I am loading my main app module in all of them, all tests make a call to that service and thus all tests fail with a

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/v1/config
No more request expected
```

I can add the following to my test suites and it fixes the problem, registering this call with the backend so it expects it.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_){
    _$httpBackend_.whenGET(/\/api\/v1\/config.*/).respond([]);
}));
```

The issue is that this would need to be added to every test suite, which in my modular app is a lot of wet code. What I'm looking for is either a way to define this expectation globally once for all tests (either in a karma global file, or I'd even settle for a service/one-line import to place in my suites) *or* if my test setup or `app.config` is set up inefficiently a way to improve that.

What I've tried so far

```
// Defined in a tests-global.js file listed in my karma files array
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_){
    _$httpBackend_.whenGET(/\/api\/v1\/req_params.*/).respond([]);
}));
```

which fails with `Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!` since in my individual test suites I am calling `beforeEach(module('x'));` to use that module's modules and you can't do that after an `inject()`.

I've also tried

```
// Defined in a tests-global.js file listed in my karma files array
beforeEach(function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ngMock']);
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\/api\/v1\/req_params.*/).respond([]);
});
```

which produces no additional error, but also does not solve the `Unexpected request` issue.

Is there any way to handle expects for all tests, or if this is a sign that my testing structure is setup badly, a way to structure my code/tests better?

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I'm not including the main service module, but a mock for it, something like (as for me I'm including it inside karma.conf in "files"):

```
angular.module('some.service', []).service('MainService', function() {
    this.APP_HOST = 'localhost';
    this.APP_PORT = 8000;
});
```

Then, inside a test in a global beforeEach (remember that MainService is a mocked one, not a real):

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, MainService, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    MainService.APP_HOST = 'localhost';
    MainService.APP_PORT = '8000';
    baseUrl = '//' + MainService.APP_HOST + ':' + MainService.APP_PORT;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    someCtrl = $controller('someCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        MainService: MainService
    });
}));
```

And will define HOW should it be mocked:

```
function mockHttpSuccessfulRequest() {
    $httpBackend
        .expectGET(baseUrl + '/api/surveys')
        .respond({
            surveys: [{
                something: false,
                date: '2015-03-11T08:28:58.765Z'
            }]
        });
}
```

So then you are defining this mock before a test suit:

`beforeEach(mockHttpSuccessfulRequest);`

And the you are free checking everything you want.